# Woocommerce: downloadable files disappear after database restore

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, database-restore

After restoring my WordPress WooCommerce database, all the **Downloadable Files** for my virtual products have disappeared.

I have queried the `wp_postmeta` table and see that the `_downloadable_files` entries are still there and I have verified that the URL's in the table are still valid.

However, the files no longer appear as links in order emails, no longer appear  in the **My Account** page, and no longer appear in the **Downloadable Files** section in the **Product Data** in the **Edit Product**.

The only fix that I know works is to manually re-enter all the files.

I'm using Apache2 and MySQL. The files are stored on the same Apache server that is serving WordPress.

I am trying to copy a development database from a different development server to a new environment
and am trying to find an efficient way to do this without having to manually re-enter all the downloadable files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into this I think that the issue is that WooCommerce is generating an MD5 of something about the Downloadable File URL which does not transfer from one server to another.

Looking at data in the WordPress `wp_postmeta` table, I see

```
mysql> SELECT post_id,meta_value FROM wordpress.wp_postmeta where meta_key='_downloadable_files';
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| post_id | meta_value                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      33 | a:1:{s:32:"fccc91f867cc071737bea5433d1c3181";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:3:"fox";s:4:"file";s:61:"http://_123456789_.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/fox.png";}}
```

My guess is that the `fccc91f867cc071737bea5433d1c3181` value is somehow not recognized as valid when the database is transferred to a new host.

To work around the issue, I wrote a PHP script to read the database and then reload the Downloadable Files using the WooCommerce REST API via Gerhard Potgieter's [WooCommerce REST API PHP client](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library).

```
<?php

error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 'On' );
require_once "class-wc-api-client.php";

$consumer_key = 'ck_examplexxx'; // Add your own Consumer Key here
$consumer_secret = 'cs_secretxxx'; // Add your own Consumer Secret here
$store_url = 'http://123456789/'; // Add the home URL to the store you want to connect to here

// Initialize the class
$wc_api = new WC_API_Client( $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $store_url );

$servername = "_dbhost_";
$username = "wordpress";
$password = "__password__";
$dbname = "wordpress";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT post_id,meta_value FROM wordpress.wp_postmeta where meta_key='_downloadable_files'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $product_id = $row["post_id"];
    $meta_value = $row["meta_value"];
    preg_match("/.+\:\"(http:\/\/.+\/wp-content\/uploads\/.+\/.+\/(.+)\..+)\".+/", $meta_value, $m);
    print_r( $wc_api->update_product( $product_id, '{
          "product": {
            "downloads": [
              {
                "name": "' . $m[2] . '",
                "file": "' . $m[1] . '"
              }
            ]
          }
        }'));
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
Fixed it by using your answer & using update_post_meta(), instead of WooCommerce REST API

```
$sql = "SELECT post_id,meta_value FROM wp_postmeta where meta_key='_downloadable_files'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
  {
    $product_id = $row["post_id"];
    $meta_value = $row["meta_value"];

    $v = explode("\"", $meta_value);

    $results = array_filter($v, function($value) {
        return strpos($value, 'https') !== false;
    });

    $file_path =  array_pop($results); 

    preg_match("/.+\:\"(https:\/\/.+\/wp-content\/uploads\/.+\/.+\/(.+)\..+)\".+/", $meta_value, $mn);

    $file_name = $mn[2];
    $md5_num =  md5( $m );

    $abe_file = array();
     $abe_file[0][$md5_num] = array(
        'name'   =>  $file_name,
        'file'   =>  $file_path
    );

    if(update_post_meta( $product_id, '_downloadable_files', $abe_file[0] ))
    {
        echo "$product_id . yay <br/>";
    }
    else{echo "waz <br/>";}


  }



} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```