# Missing virtual downloads woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a live website for someone who sells his MP3s. I have noticed now that the virtual files have no download link, after being purchased and on the product page in the backend. Thing is, I know they existed before as people have purchased MP3s without issue. So they have been lost somewhere perhaps because of a Wordpress update or theme change.

I exported my current wordpress product and variable product database and can see that the link information is actually there. I don't have any experience working with databases so this is a bit out of my depth, but I can see this:

```
<wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_file_paths]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[a:1:{s:32:"a97427231bd5a0eb7c0763ee6444bcc0";s:65:"http://domainname.com/wp-content/fl_dl/Deep-Relaxation.zip";}]]></wp:meta_value>
```

Which is the correct url for the mp3. How do I get Wordpress to realise that the links are already there? I really do not want to have to go through every product and input the link again as there are hundreds!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635202/woocommerce-downloadable-files-disappear-after-database-restore?rq=1

Comment: Hi RST, I actually saw that post but don't really understand any of the answer. What am I supposed to do with that code?

Comment: You shouldn't use any code you don't understand. Something changed in your system which makes the hashed or encrypted key for the download unusable. Your best bet it to ask WooCommerce for support or hire a developer who can look at your system.